# Google Maps V3 API Key Local Computer Error: GoogleGoogle has disabled use of the Maps API for this application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3

I'm running a rails 3 setup on my computer, just using the built in rails server and getting a Google Maps API V3 error:

```
Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html#Obtaining_Key
```

This is just on my local computer for testing. http://0.0.0.0:3000. If anybody knows how I could configure my API Key for local testing that would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I managed to get it working with localhost:port/*

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Entering a specific port number doesn't work. Entering `port` does :)

Answer (score 4):

I just had this problem with a system that previously worked. When using the Google Maps v3 API(javascript), if I included my key(which allows 'localhost' as a referrer, specified in API console), Google would reject it and tell me the key was disabled. If I changed it to pass in no key at all(blank), it works fine...

Comment: This worked for me, it is strange that we have to do this though as the API key I had generated previously was working on my localhost for the morning, it was only after a few hours that I got this error. Regenerating keys does not fix this either.

Answer (score 1):

The key system has changed recently, and full details haven't been published. It took some time for the community to work out the effects of the validation in the previous system.

If you're running on localhost then I believe any valid key works. As you're running on 0.0.0.0, you will probably need to specify that ip address in the API Console. You may need to specify 0.0.0.0:3000, depending on what is passed to Google as the referrer.

Comment: i have tried so many combinations, including http://localhost, http://0.0.0.0, http://0.0.0.0:3000, http://localhost:3000 none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

One problem might be you are referring the google-api more than once.So first check that.And for checking that you can open the same url of your application in another browser.
Secondly check the referers which you had given while generating the key.
To verify that the problem really exist on referral first don't give reference just allow everyone(i m assuming you are testing locally) and test it then you will get the idea where the problem exist and correct it by providing proper referal(for local use "http://localhost").

And the third problem might be with the API as google making frequent changes and the documentation is not yet proper for that.
But i am sure by applying above thing your problem will be solved.

As the same problem i faced bcz i am referencing twice at a time because the port i left opened.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need a key for version 3 of the google maps api.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html
Might you be sending an invalid key?

Comment: i don't think it's an invalid key, and i have tried two different keys (one i had working last year in august api 3, and another one i created yesterday since the other one wasn't working. both should be api 3). i just think it has to do with the valid referrers and something to do with running it locally on my mac with rails server.

Comment: Did you try creating a key based off of 0.0.0.0 or not passing a key at all?

Comment: thanks John, it seems the only way i can get the map to load is to not include the key at all, i just dropped the ?key= param and the map loaded.

Comment: if you don't mind upvoting my initial question that would be cool, i think that this will be useful for people who are testing locally. i couldn't find information about local testing and not including a key online anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

after many tries it's works for me, I just **generate a new key**.

Answer (score 0):

For me just works generating 'Key for browser apps' and set in 'Referers':

```
http://localhost:3000/*
```